# Suitescript 2.0 Adding 3rd party libraries

Tags: suitescript2.0

I have been watching the instructional videos on Youtube from Stoic Software and have tried uploading the following to my Netsuite account to test the creation of third party libraries:

```
    /**
 * Prompts the user if the current project has not been re-baselined in some time
 *
 * @copyright 2020 Stoic Software, LLC
 * @author Eric T Grubaugh <eric@stoic.software>
 *
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope Public
 * @NAmdConfig ./amdconfig.json
 * @appliedtorecord job
 */

define(["moment"], (moment) => {
  const message = "Project has not been re-baselined in over two months.";

  function pageInit(context) {
    let lastBaseline = moment(
      context.currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: "lastbaselinedate" })
    );

    if (lastBaseline.isValid() && moment().diff(lastBaseline, "months") >= 2) {
      alert(message);
    }
  }

  return { pageInit };
});
```

This is the amdconfig.json file that sits in the same location as the script:

```
    {
  "paths": {
    "moment": "./SuiteScripts/sdf_ignore/moment-with-locales.js"
  }
}
```

When I try to create the script record, I get the following error:
[image]

Row 14 is the following: `define(["moment"], (moment)` => `{`

Can anyone see what the issue is?

Edit: thanks to @fullstack.studio I was able to upload the script.

I am getting the following error message though where it is not recognising the function:
[image: error message]

the third party library I am trying to use is the one found under:
https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use path without '.' => `/SuiteScripts/...`. The '.' is a ref to the current folder. And you may remove the `.js` ext.

```
"paths": {
        "helper": "/SuiteScripts/My_Helper"
      }
```

In the meta try to use `2.1` instead `2.x`

```
/**
....
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
....
 */
```

Comment: Thank you! That has got rid of the error message....

There is still an issue with the script itself but at least deploying the third party library seems to have worked

Comment: welcome. np. if the answer is the fix for your issue. don't forget to mark it as resolved. this is a ref. for other user. :)